# Crystal Report Database Connection fails

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm implementing a Windows Form, and on a button click it should print a Report with CrystalReportViewer.
I'm developing it in Visual Studio 2017, and in my machine are installed CR runtime both 32 and 64 bit.

This is my code:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

..............
..............
        ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

        string path = "my//report//path.rpt";
        cryrpt.Load(path);

        Tables CrTables;

        crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "MyServerName";
        crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "MyDatabaseName";
        crconnectioninfo.UserID = "MyUserName";
        crconnectioninfo.Password = "MyPassword";
        
        CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (Table crtable in CrTables)
        {
            crtablelogoninfo = crtable.LogOnInfo;
            crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo;
            crtable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt;
```

It works fine on my machine, and some others.

When I build it in release mode, and install the application to another machines, someone works and other not. The error is that the report can not connect to database.

I tried to ping the server, and it is ok.

Here is the Stack trace of the Exception:

```
Stack Trace:   in CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.GetLastPageNumber(RequestContext pRequestContext)
  in CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetLastPageNumber(ReportPageRequestContext reqContext)

Inner Source: rptcontrollers.dll

HResult: 2147217393
```

In all machines are installed CRRuntime (the same I have on mine!).
Maybe I miss some dependencies, but don't know which.

I noticed that it doesn't work on machines that have not Visual Studio installed. But I cannot install Visual Studio on all PCs.

I can't find a similar issue on the web.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message or screen that you are receiving?

Comment: Simply "Connection to Database failed"

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report uses sql connectivity sdk to connect to Database.

these are the features to install in order to let the connection work:

Client Tools Connectivity

Client Tools Backwards Compatibility

Client Tools SDK

Management Tools – Basic

Management Tools – Complete

SQL Client Connectivity SDK

download page [here](https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check the non-working computers to see if they are missing any Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables in comparison to the working computers.  I have attached a screenshot of a Procmon trace running a sample application that uses the Crystal Viewer.  The trace shows that the C++ redistributables are called.  If that is not it, try running Procmon to see if any dependencies are missing.

[Procmon trace showing C++ redistributables are called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RxIc.png)